# Building contingency table

Tags: r, contingency

I have a table like this:

```
df <- data.frame(P1 = c(1,0,0,0,0,0,"A"),
                  P2 = c(0,-2,1,2,1,0,"A"),
                  P3 = c(-1,2,0,2,1,0,"B"),
                  P4 = c(2,0,-1,0,-1,0,"B"),
                  Names = c("G1","G2","G3","G1","G2","G3","Group"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Which becomes

```
Names    P1   P2    P3   P4
G1       1    0     -1   2
G2       0    -2    2    0
G3       0    1     0    -1
G1       0    2     2    0
G2       0    1     1    -1
G3       0    0     0    0
Group    A    A     B    B
```

Here, `A` and `B` are grouping variables for `P1, P2, P3, P4`.

I want to build a contingency for `Ids` (`G1`, `G2`...), `Group` (`A`,`B`), and `Var` (`-2,-1,0,1,2`) table such as:

```
Id    Group Var    Count
G1    A     -2     0
G1    A     -1     0
G1    A     0      1
G1    A     1      1
G1    A     2      0
G1    B     -2     0
G1    B     -1     1
G1    B     0      0
G1    B     1      0
G1    B     2      1
G2    A     -2     1
G2    A     -1     0
G2    A     0      1
...
```

Is there a way to do it in R without using lots of loops?

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: Thanks @Sotos, I added the df

Comment: I think your output is not coherent with your `df` : shouldn't `Group` be a variable ? it appears in a row...

Comment: It is in a row, but I just added it there to make it easy to see. The output should show the count, per `Group`, per `G#`

Comment: If you prefer, `Group` was derived from another dataframe and in this way I am pooling info from both dataframes to build the table

Comment: Also, I appreciate that if you downvote you give me a reason for the downvote, or else I won't know how to improve the post.

Comment: Sorry I still don't see then how A and B can be used to group your data... and I didn't downvote :-)

Comment: ... or does P1 and P2 belong to A and P3, P4 belong to B ?

Comment: @mdag02 thanks so much for your comments. The idea is that you group columns by `A` and `B`. This way, `P1` and `P2` are contained in `A`; `P3` and `P4` are contained in `B`. It's as if instead of having a row with that value you would have a grouping variable `Group`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to group the `P1` & `P2` columns as `A` and the `P3` & `P4` columns as `B`, you could approach it as follows with the `data.table`-package:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- melt(melt(setDT(df),
                measure.vars = list(c(2,3),c(4,5)),
                value.name = c("A","B")),
           id = 1, measure.vars = 3:4, variable.name = 'group'
           )[order(Id,group)][, val2 := value]

DT[CJ(Id = Id, group = group, value = value, unique = TRUE)
   , on = .(Id, group, value)
   ][, .(counts = sum(!is.na(val2))), by = .(Id, group, value)]
```

which results in:

> ```
>     Id group value counts
>  1: G1     A    -2      0
>  2: G1     A    -1      0
>  3: G1     A     0      2
>  4: G1     A     1      1
>  5: G1     A     2      1
>  6: G1     B    -2      0
>  7: G1     B    -1      1
>  8: G1     B     0      1
>  9: G1     B     1      0
> 10: G1     B     2      2
> 11: G2     A    -2      1
> 12: G2     A    -1      0
> 13: G2     A     0      2
> 14: G2     A     1      1
> 15: G2     A     2      0
> 16: G2     B    -2      0
> 17: G2     B    -1      1
> 18: G2     B     0      1
> 19: G2     B     1      1
> 20: G2     B     2      1
> 21: G3     A    -2      0
> 22: G3     A    -1      0
> 23: G3     A     0      3
> 24: G3     A     1      1
> 25: G3     A     2      0
> 26: G3     B    -2      0
> 27: G3     B    -1      1
> 28: G3     B     0      3
> 29: G3     B     1      0
> 30: G3     B     2      0
> ```

---

Used data:

```
df <- read.table(text="Id       P1   P2   P3    P4   
G1     1    0    -1    2 
G2     0    -2   2     0 
G3     0    1    0     -1
G1     0    2    2     0 
G2     0    1    1     -1 
G3     0    0    0     0", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

*Note that I omitted the 'Group'-row because you stated in the comments that these were just to indicated to which groups the `P1` - `P4` columns should belong.*

Answer (score 1):

With

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text="Id       P1   P2   P3    P4   
G1     1    0    -1    2 
G2     0    -2   2     0 
G3     0    1    0     -1
G1     0    2    2     0 
G2     0    1    1     -1 
G3     0    0    0     0", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

We reshape the table and recode the `P*` variables in `group`.
We then count and complete the missing cases. Resulting in :

```
df %>%
  gather(P1, P2, P3, P4, key = "p", value = "v") %>% 
  mutate(group = ifelse(p %in% c("P1", "P2"), "A", "B")) %>% 
  group_by(Id, group, v) %>% 
  summarise(Count = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  complete(Id, group, v, fill = list("Count" = 0))
```

And if you don't need all combinations in the output, just use :

```
df %>%
  gather(P1, P2, P3, P4, key = "p", value = "v") %>% 
  mutate(group = ifelse(p %in% c("P1", "P2"), "A", "B")) %>% 
  group_by(Id, group, v) %>% 
  summarise(Count = n())

# A tibble: 17 x 4
# Groups:   Id, group [?]
      Id    group  v     Count
      <chr> <chr>  <int> <int>
 1    G1     A     0     2
 2    G1     A     1     1
 3    G1     A     2     1
 4    G1     B    -1     1
 5    G1     B     0     1
 6    G1     B     2     2
 7    G2     A    -2     1
 8    G2     A     0     2
 9    G2     A     1     1
10    G2     B    -1     1
11    G2     B     0     1
12    G2     B     1     1
13    G2     B     2     1
14    G3     A     0     3
15    G3     A     1     1
16    G3     B    -1     1
17    G3     B     0     3
```